# REST API route for SMS Opt Outs?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, rest, mobileconnect, sms

Hey QQ on Mobile Connect REST API for Marketing Cloud - we can retrieve subscriptions that show what keywords a mobile number is opted in to, but can we also retrieve subscriptions that they've OPTED OUT of? The route /sms/v1/contacts/subscriptions appears to be only good for opt in status and I did not see a similar route to return opt outs.

Answer (score 2):

As i was brainstorming, what we COULD do is create a query definition from within Marketing Cloud, have that populate a data extension with Opt Out/Opt In data, then use REST to pull relevant data from that DE.